# Algorithm for 2-coloring classes of 3-uniform hypergraphs

Tags: graph-colorings, hypergraph

Hi all and thanks in advance for your efforts.

I'm interested in 2-coloring 3-uniform hypergraphs. I know that in general, the problem of deciding if a 3-uniform hypergraph is 2-colorable is NP-hard. I wonder if there are any (non-trivial) subclasses of 3-uniform hypergraphs for which there exists a polynomial algorithm for 2-coloring. For example, are there some $H_1,...,H_k$ for which the class of $(H_1,...,H_k)$-free 3-uniform hypergraphs has a polynomial algorithm for 2-coloring? Are there any results of this type?

Thanks, 
Lior

Comment: Please define 2-colouring for hypergraphs.  There are many definitions around.

Comment: By "coloring" I mean a coloring of the vertices such that there is no monochromatic edge.

Comment: you should rather post on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

This problem is the same as MONOTONE NOT-ALL-EQUAL-3-SAT (perhaps you will find useful references by searching for this problem), where you have a set $C$ of 3-clauses from a variable set $X$ and you want a boolean assignment for $X$ so that each clause contains a true and a false variable ("monotone" stands  for "no negated variables").

In this terminology, Moret showed that MONOTONE NOT-ALL-EQUAL-3-SAT is polynomial-time solvable when the clause-variable (bipartite) incidence graph of the instance is planar ([Planar NAE3SAT is in P, B. Moret, ACM SIGACT News, Volume 19 Issue 2, Summer 1988](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/49097.49099)).

In the terminology of hypergraph coloring, this translates to the edge-vertex (bipartite) incidence graph of the input hypergraph being planar.